# How to debug "Xcode CodeSign error: The entitlements file Entitlements.plist is missing" in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, code-signing

Xcode throws this error when I try to CMD+I (Profile) an app on the device. Running is fine. Just profiling doesn't work and gives this error.

The path to the Entitlements.plist is bogus and points to a location that doesn't exist anymore.

I don't want to do Ad-Hoc Distribution, just profile my app on the device.

I'm finding only Xcode 3.2 related resources about this issue. Has anyone else encountered this with Xcode 4 and found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy your Entitlements.plist file into the root directory of your project.  If  you don't have one anymore, then create one and put it in your default bundle.  There's (for once) no magic going on here.

Comment: How to create Entitlements.plist? And what is it's purpose?

Comment: In XCode, File/New File, under iOS select "Code Signing", then select Entitlements in the right pane, Next, Save.  Open it - there is a single key: get-task-allow.  Set this to YES if you are going to be running it with a debugger in XCode.  Set it to NO if you are sending out IPA files to testers or submitting to the app store.  See this for more info:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1710/_index.html

Comment: Really it's very help full.because i am getting same problem.
thanks Rayfleck

Comment: I dont have that option "Code Signing". I went to Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Entitlements and deleted entry there.