# ERROR ITMS-90045: “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements

Tags: expo, testflight

I'm very new to react native and expo but I've managed to get an app working well through the expo app but when I go to deliver via Xcode my app that I generated from expo I get this message below, I've google everywhere but I'm really struggling.

> ERROR ITMS-90045: “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application
>   bundle’s signature contains code signing entitlements that are not
>   supported on iOS. Specifically, key ‘com.apple.developer.user-fonts’
>   in ‘Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp’ is not supported.”

Any help would be most appreciated.

So I installed expo and all relevant programs on a new install mac and created a blank app with just some plain text. Managed to build it ok using `expo build:ios` and everything went great. I then used the `expo upload:ios` and entered my apple id and pw and it started doing it magic. After several minutes I receive the same message as before

> ERROR ITMS-90045 : “Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your
>   application bundle’s signature contains code signing entitlements that
>   are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key
>   ‘com.apple.developer.user-fonts’ in
>   ‘Payload/ExpoKitApp.app/ExpoKitApp’ is not supported.”

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43053859/error-itms-90045-invalid-code-signing-entitlements-xamarin-studio)

change Entitlements.plist to this

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but with using expo i cant find a Entitlements.plist file.
Is there something in the expo config i need to change?

Comment: It is in your project folder and if there are no Entitlements.plist files then you can create it refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315372/how-to-debug-xcode-codesign-error-the-entitlements-file-entitlements-plist-is

Comment: Thanks but still no joy. I creaed the Entitlements.plist in the root project folder and added this code

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
  </dict>
</plist>


Then I reran the expo build:ios command. It ran and then I tried to push it up again and i get the same error message